# fscanf to read an array of floats, but only getting first number in array

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

Reading a file, first number is an `int` that's the size of the array, then the rest are `double`

Here is the function:

```
void read1dascii(double** a, int* m, char* infile)
{
 FILE * fp = fopen(infile, "r");

 fscanf(fp, "%d", m);
 alloc1d(a, *m);

 fscanf(fp, "%lf\n", *a);

 fclose(fp);
}
```

Here is the `alloc1d` function it calls:

```
void alloc1d(double** a, int m)
{
 *a = malloc(sizeof(double) * m);
}
```

I'm getting the first number which is the size and then the first number in array, but then the rest are reading in as zeros.

Comment: At the moment, there are two answers.  Both have good elements; both are missing something that the other has.  You need to adopt the good bits of both in your code.  You also need to check that the memory allocation succeeds and decide what to do if it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read all of them using loop.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < *m; ++i) {
  fscanf(fp, "%lf", *a + i);
}
```

Comment: thank you!...I had tried that previously but instead of *a  + i, I was doing *a[i]

Comment: You need to check the status of `fscanf()` — as well as keep the bounds checking that you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
fscanf(fp, "%lf\n", *a);
```

Here you are only reading once, so it's just receiving the first float, to read the rest of the array, you need something like

```
while ( fscanf(fp, "%lf\n", &a) == 1 ) 
{
    /* do stuff with 'a' here */
}
```

Comment: You need to check the bounds  of the array — as well as checking the status of `fscanf()` as you are doing.